# Unconnected lookup input value not working

Tags: informatica

In **Informatica**, I am trying to get the **date after certain working days** (say 10,20,30) based on another conditions ( say `prio` 1,2,3). Already I have one `DIM_DATE` table where holidays and working days are configured. There is no relation with priority table and DIM_DATE table.Here I am using one unconnected lookup with doing the query override. Below the query I used:

```
select day_date as DAY_DATE
--,rank1
--,PRIORITY_name 
from (
select day_date as DAY_DATE,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY day_date) as RANK1,PRIORITY_name as PRIORITY_NAME from (
select date_id,day_date from dim_date where day_date  between   to_date('10.15.2018','MM.DD.YYYY')   and  to_date('10.15.2018','MM.DD.YYYY') +interval '250' DAY(3) and working_day=1
)
,DIM_PRIORITY
where DIM_PRIORITY.PRIORITY_name='3'
) where  rank1=10
order by RANK1 --
```

In this example I have hardcoded the `day_date`,`priority_name`,`rank1`. But I need to pass all of them as input coming from mapping.

This hardcode is working but while taking as input like `?created?` then it is not working. Here created is the date which will come from mapping flow.

1. Could you please suggest if this is feasible which I am trying?
2. `?created?` is giving error missing right paranthesis but the hardcoded query is running fine in sql.

Comment: Formatting, highlighting of relevant parts

Comment: Any suggestion plz

Answer (score 0):

You match your incoming port against one of the return fields of one of the records in the cache via the lookup condition (not by feeding ports into the override itself).

If this is not possible for you for some unexplained reason then you could define 3 mapping variables and set them to be equal to each of the input ports you care about (using setvariable) before feeding the record in to the lookup. Then use the variables in your lookup override

Comment: Hi Daniel,Thanks for the response. I tried using 2nd option using setvariable for 3 different mapping variable. But as expected mapping variable is not changing though out session. Input ports must change for each row based on the input source data. Using mapping variable it only picks the first row value and then not changing for the 2nd input row.

Comment: Hmmm fair point, only option I can think of is to remove the override (if that means creating a view in the db thdn so be it) , cache all the possible return values at the start of the sesdion and then use the input ports in your lookup condition. Not surd how many records you'll have to cache for this - could be better than querying the db for each input row